# How do I tell XeLaTeX where to find the .bbl files?

Tags: bibtex, xetex, include

I am trying to compile a multi-chapter dissertation. I am using `chapterbib` so I run `bibtex` on each chapter.

```
xelatex dissertation
bibtex chapters/chapter1
bibtex chapters/chapter2
xelatex dissertation
xelatex dissertation
```

The requisite `.bbl` and `.aux` files are generated in the `chapters` directory. However, when I run `xelatex` after `bibtex` none of the citations are found. If I cut and paste the contents of the `.bbl` into the main `.tex` then it produces the desired output.

Do I need to use some sort of `bib-include` statement in the main document so it properly searches the `chapters` directory?

Here is a minimal example:

dissertation.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\include{chapters/chapter1}
\include{chapters/chapter2}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

ref.bib:

```
@misc{ref1,
    title = "reference1"
}

@misc{ref2,
    title = "reference2"
}
```

chapters/chapter1.tex:

```
\cite{ref1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{ref}
```

chapters/chapter2.tex:

```
\cite{ref2}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike2}
\bibliography{ref}
```

Comment: We probably need to know the setup of your dissertation. How are the chapters included.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a simple package include statement:

```
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
```